# Hadoop User Addition in Secured Cluster

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

We are using a kerborized CDH cluster. While adding a user to the cluster, we used to add the user only to the gateway/edge nodes as in any hadoop distro cluster. But with the newly added userIDs, we are not able to execute map-reduce/yarn jobs and throwing "user not found" exception.

When I researched through this, I came across a link https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/SecureContainer.html , which says to execute the yarn jobs in the secured cluster, we might need to have the corresponding user in all the nodes as the secure containers execute under the credentials of the job user.

So we added the corresponding userID to all the nodes and the jobs are getting executed.
If this is the case and if the cluster has around 100+ nodes, user provisioning for each userID would became a tedious job.

Can anyone please suggest any other effective way, if you came across the same scenario in your project implementation?

Comment: Any pointers to this issue, please?

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches ordered by difficulty (from simple to painful).

One is to have a job-runner user that everyone uses to run jobs.

Another one is to use a configuration management tool to sync /etc/passwd and /etc/group (chef, puppet) on your cluster at regular intervals (1 hr - 1 day) or use a cron job to do this.

Otherwise you can buy or use open source Linux/UNIX user mapping services like Centrify (commercial), VAS (commercial), FreeIPA (free) or SSSD (free).

If you have an Active Directory server or LDAP server use the Hadoop LDAP user mappings.

References:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/57394/what-are-the-best-practises-for-unix-user-mapping.html

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cm_sg_ldap_grp_mappings.html